# Error in Mulesoft Anypoint sudio not able to run or deploy mule project in Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule

I am getting below error in Anypoint Studio while running or deploying mule application I followed the steps given in the web link of the error but still getting same error.

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".m2\repository". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this, either use the Run/Debug configurations, and add the build target there. Or you can specify what maven should use as default settings. (See screenshot for sensible defaults (skip unit tests as they often fail during development) )

[image: Maven command line arguments]